# Add columns to table scraped from web VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, the code pulls in the whole data table from trates.org. I would like to add a column that fills down a formula -see final lines of code-. When I run the code, the formula only fills down the first two rows. Additionally, when I run ClearSheet, the two additional column does not clear. Thank you for all your help.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Call ClearSheet
    Call UseQueryTable2

End Sub

Private Sub ClearSheet()

    For Each table In Sheet4.QueryTables
        table.Delete
    Next table

    Sheet4.Cells.Clear

End Sub

Public Sub UseQueryTable2()

  Dim url As String
    url = "https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2023"

    ' Add the new QueryTable
    Dim table As QueryTable
    Set table = Sheet4.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & url, Sheet4.Range("A1"))
    
    With table
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables ' return entire web page
        .WebTables = "1"
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll ' web formatting.
        .Refresh
    End With

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("x1:x" & LastRow).Formula = "=month(A3)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set BackgroundQuery to False to allow the query to finish before continuing with your code. Also, you should qualify your range references.  And, you can allow your code to determine the next available column.

```
Public Sub UseQueryTable2()

    Dim url As String
    url = "https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2023"

    ' Add the new QueryTable
    Dim table As QueryTable
    Set table = Sheet4.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & url, Sheet4.Range("A1"))
    
    With table
        .BackgroundQuery = False ' wait for query to finish before continuing
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables ' return entire web page
        .WebTables = "1"
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll ' web formatting.
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    With Sheet4

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim NextCol As Long
        NextCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        
        .Range(.Cells(2, NextCol), .Cells(LastRow, NextCol)).Formula = "=month(A2)"
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```